# merge two (uint8_t*) pointers and conver to decimal

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

I have a problem with the data coming from an accelerometer. I am able to read the accelerometer but the data comes as a pointer (uint8_t*). Well, I am quite new to C but I think it is a pointer. So I have to values, for example: 0x1B and the LSB 0x29.

I need to merge those values into one value and convert it to decimal.

So, in binary format 0x1B= 0001 1011 and 0x29=0010 1001

I want this value 0001 1011 0010 1001 = 6953

I have seen some code to merge the values using byte defined values.

Result = (Value1 << 8) | Value0;

If someone can help me to properly understand how to convert the pointers into decimal values so I can make more complex math calculations I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: a pointer is the physical adress of a piece of memory. Converting it to decimal will return garbage data only. I presume you want the thing that is stored in the variable the pointer is pointing at.

Comment: You have it.  After the shift and or, 'Result' contains the value, in binary.  If you 'convert' that value into anything else, eg an, ASCII decimal string, you will lose the ability to easily do further computations with software.

Comment: A number is a number. Hexadecimal, binary, octal, decimal, etc are just representations of the *same* number. Therefore, the `Result`you have shown can already be used as a decimal number (or hex or octal or binary, etc). But since you have not shown any real code we can't really tell whether that is actually what you really mean.

Comment: Most likely the `uint8_t*` is part of the code interface to the accelerometer, I would guess it is a parameter to a function in the driver? (an SPI or I2C driver?) In which case it points to a buffer where the data is stored. In which case nothing of what you attempt to do makes any sense at all.

Comment: Please provide a snippet of code where you found the `uint8_t*` so we get some context.

Comment: The value of the pointer itself will not relate directly to the sensor data (that's what indirection is all about).  You need two things to answer your question: 1) understand C, 2) Understand the sensor manufacturer's API and/or device datasheet.  Plenty of people can help you with (1), but without further details (2) is opaque to all of us.  What you must do depends on the documented interface, and you have not provided that information.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try if one of these functions is able to convert the pointer into an integer value... these should be compilable on just about any 8-bit machine.

```
int ResultBigEndian (void *byteptr) {
    unsigned char *b=byteptr;
    return (b[0] << 8) + (b[1]);
}

int ResultLittleEndian (void *byteptr) {
    unsigned char *b=byteptr;
    return (b[1] << 8) + (b[0]);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't just do `(uint16_t)the pointer`? It is portable, since the pointer and the integer type will have the same endianess on any machine. Anyway, I very much doubt this is actually what the OP needs.

Comment: @Lundin Well, perhaps to help him understand the problem a little better... I'd obviously try your approach first, I just wanted to isolate the problem into a c function which can take any pointer as argument and to demonstrate the effect of endianness. If the endianness is correct and the pointer is aligned properly, then your cast works. But I'm just thinking why the result is given as a 8-bit pointer instead of an integer pointer and that the reason might be is that it's some hardware data copied verbatim and it might be in wrong endianness... just guessing here, really...

Comment: @FUZxxl Umm misaligned how? This case would be a 16 bit address bus, in which case I very much doubt the compiler would store pointers at misaligned addresses, if the 16 bit CPU has some obscure alignment requirement. In any case, masking the individual bytes won't help.

Comment: @Lundin, it could be that the data comes from some bus as a burst of 8-bit values, which are read byte by byte with some function and stored into memory as such. In that case, the binary values are not generated by a compiler, it may be some binary mish-mash that some hardware vomits and it's pure luck if the data is aligned or in correct endianness, or indeed even in two's complement format and the number of bits may or may not be divisible by 8 (some output 12-bit data). In the worst case it may need to be reassembled and reinterpreted bit by bit - although probably not... but it happens...

Comment: @PkP All communication protocols have their own endianess specified, and alignment doesn't apply at all. Anyway, there's no point in guessing, I doubt it is possible to answer the question in its current state.

Comment: This may answer the question - but it is the wrong question.  It seems unlikely it will solve the root problem which seems to be lack of understanding of the sensor API.  Converting the pointer to an integer seems unlikely to result in any useful sensor data because that is not where the data is.  The OP needs to understand the concept of indirection and to refer to the documentation to determine what the data means.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "comes as a pointer". The data you recieve is binary format data. What its represented as is superflous to what you want to do with it. If you evaluate it as a decimal number, it will be one. Its important to know what format your data comes in, but nothing like that "comes as a pointer". If you are certain whatever your given is your desired data in decimal, you can use it as decimal.

A pointer, however, is the physical adress of a variable that the program has assigned it at the time of initialization or memory allocation. Its typically represented as a hexadecimal number. But that number is basicly random on multiple executions of the same program.